# jQuery $(this) keyword is not working in a plugin

Tags: jquery

I am working on this demo. Why is the `this` not functioning here? As you can see clicking in each button is affecting on other `.btn-nums` while it should only affect on

```
var out = this.find('.btn-nums');
```

because of `this.find('.btn-nums')`

```js
(function($) {
   $.fn.spiner = function() {
      var temp = 0.0;
      var inc = this.find('.btn-add');
      var out = this.find('.btn-nums');    
      var dec = this.find('.btn-less'); 
      var step = $(this).data('step');
      
      inc.on("mousedown", function() {
         temp =  temp + step;
         out.html(temp);
      })
   }
}(jQuery));

$('.spiner').spiner();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spiner" data-step="0.5">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-less">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-nums">0.00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add">+</button>
</div>


<div class="spiner" data-step="1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-less">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-nums">0.00</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: replace this with $(this)

Comment: @NawedKhan true,but it still don't solve the problem because `$(this)` would represent both `$('.spiner')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `$(this).each()`.

If you don't add `$(this).each()` then `$(this)` represents both `$('.spiner')`

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.spiner = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
      var temp = 0.0;
      var inc = $(this).find('.btn-add');
      var out = $(this).find('.btn-nums');
      var dec = $(this).find('.btn-less');
      var step = $(this).data('step');

      inc.on("mousedown", function() {
        temp = temp + step;
        out.html(temp);
      })
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.spiner').spiner();
```

**Demo**

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.spiner = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
      var temp = 0.0;
      var inc = $(this).find('.btn-add');
      var out = $(this).find('.btn-nums');
      var dec = $(this).find('.btn-less');
      var step = $(this).data('step');

      inc.on("mousedown", function() {
        temp = temp + step;
        out.html(temp);
      })
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.spiner').spiner();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spiner" data-step="0.5">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-less">-</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-nums">0.00</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-add">+</button>
</div>


<div class="spiner" data-step="1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-less">-</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-nums">0.00</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-add">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to establish decrement as well =)

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.spiner = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
      var temp = 0.0;
      var inc = $(this).find('.btn-add');
      var out = $(this).find('.btn-nums');
      var dec = $(this).find('.btn-less');
      var step = $(this).data('step');

      inc.on("mousedown", function() {
        temp = temp + step;
        out.html(temp);
      })
      dec.on("mousedown", function() {
        temp = temp - step;
        out.html(temp);
      })
    });
  }
}(jQuery));

$('.spiner').spiner();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spiner" data-step="0.5">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-less">-</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-nums">0.00</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-add">+</button>
</div>


<div class="spiner" data-step="1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-less">-</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-nums">0.00</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-add">+</button>
</div>
```